# Use pan gestures to rotate view in one corner swift

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a swiping future to a view, but I want it to move by moving the finger tip on it, around a corner of the view and when it reach a certain point, it stop moving.

I did it with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`but it moves automatically with animation, also the it's not exactly rotating around corner

```
  let swipeToRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeRight))
        swipeToRight.direction = .right
        container.addGestureRecognizer(swipeToRight)




  @objc func respondToSwipeRight(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { [weak self] in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
            this.container.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: .init(x: 1, y: 1))
            this.container.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 15.degreesToRadians)
            haptic.impactOccurred()
                        
        }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            
            this.rotateContainerToInitialPosition()
        })
    }
```

I want to do it with pan gestures or something similar that it let the view to move exactly with finger, and come back when it's released , but I don't know how to do it. could anyone show me how? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to rotate the box as the user moves their finger right and left. Be sure to start your pan gesture on the box.

Start with a new iOS app project. Use the following for the `ViewController` class. No other changes to the project are needed. Run on your favorite iOS device or simulator.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var box: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let container = UIView(frame: .zero)
        container.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(container)

        // Just some example constraints to put the box on the screen
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),
            container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor),
            container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -30),
            container.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
        ])

        // The box that will be rotated
        // Sized to match the blue container
        box = UIView(frame: container.bounds)
        box.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        box.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        box.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1) // bottom-right corner for rotation
        container.addSubview(box)

        // Setup the pan gesture and add to the blue container
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panHandler))
        pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
        pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        container.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }

    @objc func panHandler(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .began || gesture.state == .changed {
            // Relative offset from the start of the gesture
            let offset = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view)

            // Ignore moves to the left of the starting point
            let right = max(offset.x, 0)

            // Only rotate up to 75 degrees - just an example
            let angleDeg = min(right / box.bounds.size.width * 90, 75)

            // Create and set the rotation transform on the green box
            let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angleDeg / 180 * .pi)
            box.transform = rotate
        }
    }
}
```

Start a pan in the box - move right and left and the green box rotates back and forth as the finger moves. Start a new pan and the rotation resets.

---

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the code if I want to have this on both direction?

Comment: It already supports panning in both directions. Or are you asking about having the ability to rotate about both the bottom-right and bottom-left corners depending on the initial direction of the pan?

Comment: Yes exactly, I really need to have the ability to rotate both the bottom-right and bottom-left corners depending on the initial direction of the pan

Comment: The answer posted to this question answers this question. I posted another answer on the other question since it is a different problem.